# Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes in .Net Core Web API

Tags: visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1, nuget-package-restore, asp.net-apicontroller

I'm working on a .Net Core 3.1 Web API project. I want to add an `API Controller using Entity Framework`. But it keep generating an error. It says, **"There was an error running the selected code generator: Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes."**

I installed the NuGet packages under version 3.1 too. I tried clearing all NuGet caches, but it didn't work.
How can I fix this? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the comparasion with the code and configuration in the project, it seemed no error in the project, so OP tried to create a new .net 5 project and this time everything performing like a charm. Maybe it can be a tip for similar issue, that is changing the version of the framework of the project.

===================================================

Google the error message I really found that the high voted answer asked to clear Nuget caches but as you said it not working. I'm afraid I need your help you check where's the differences between yours and mine because it worked in my side. By the way, using `v3.1.18 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` also worked for me, so my guess it may result from your visual studio client. You may reinstall the client.

I newly created an asp.net core 3.1 api project, and installed ef:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.9" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And in the startup, I modified my ConfigureService method:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddDbContext<LocaldbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Localtest")));
        }
```

And this is a test controller:

```
using WebApplication1.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class LocaldbController : Controller
    {
        private readonly LocaldbContext _context;
        public LocaldbController(LocaldbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet("/getUser")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchString)
        {
            var users = from m in _context.user
                        select m;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                users = users.Where(s => s.user_name.Contains(searchString));
            }
            return Ok(await users.ToListAsync());
        }
    }
}
```

And Dbcontext file:

```
using WebApplication1.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace WebApplication1.Data
{
    public class LocaldbContext: DbContext
    {
        public LocaldbContext(DbContextOptions<LocaldbContext> options) : base(options){}

        public DbSet<LocalMallUser> user { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<LocalMallUser>().ToTable("MallUser");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice. I rechecked all my files, controllers and methods and they were configured right. I just couldn't figure out why the error still kept popping up. So I just switched the .Net Core version to `v5`, cleared all NuGet caches and tried again. And it worked. Continuing with `v5` right now.

Comment: @KDeven Thanks for your reply and it seems that you changing your `.Net Core 3.1 project` to `.Net 5 project` made the issue disappeared. It still sounds like an issue related to SDK version. Anyway, problems solved is Ok : ) I'll update your trying in my post and could you pls accept it as the answer to end this case? Thanks for your effort on it.